# Any PPAs for Google's Go Language?

Tags: ppa, programming, golang

Do you know of any URLs for PPAs of Google's Go Language?

Comment: Does anybody know of binary packages (.deb) of gccgo 4.7 or later for Ubuntu Lucid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a PPA for Go. It worked for me, just now, and is maintained with golang versions for 10.04-12.04.

- https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/go

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gophers/go
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install golang-stable
  ```

Substitute `golang-weekly` or `golang-tip` if you want more up to date snapshots.

References:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Go
- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

EDIT: unfortunately the Gophers archive is now discontinued (see the PPA description and http://blog.labix.org/2013/06/15/in-flight-deb-packages-of-go), now replaced by a custom binary that can be used to generate Go deb packages from source.

However, the `golang` package currently in Trusty is relatively recent (1.2.1 at the time of this writing). If you are still on 12.04, you might want to use this backports PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~bcandrea/+archive/ubuntu/backports

  ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bcandrea/backports
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install golang
  ```

which I maintain trying to keep up with stable updates in official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I've installed this PPA and I seem to have all the relevant packages installed (stable version). But where are the executables? I'm trying the usual ones - 6g and 6l are not in the path.

Comment: No support for `14.04`... :-(

Comment: ...aaaaand it's yet another dead PPA without packages for current versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please unmark this answer as the right one, it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 43):

2023 answer: If you're using Ubuntu between 16.04 and 22.04 on amd64, arm64, armhf or i386, you can use the [recommended](https://go.dev/wiki/Ubuntu#using-ppa) `ppa:longsleep/golang-backports`.

It provides Golang from version 1.8 to 1.21

You can read more info on [https://launchpad.net/~longsleep/+archive/ubuntu/golang-backports](https://launchpad.net/%7Elongsleep/+archive/ubuntu/golang-backports).

To sum it up:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install golang-go
```

> Note that golang-go installs latest Go as default Go. If you do not want that, install `golang-1.19` instead and use the binaries from `/usr/lib/go-1.19/bin` for example.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, there is no PPA for the latest upstream version of Go available. To install the current Go version you can use [godeb](https://github.com/niemeyer/godeb), which automatically installs the latest upstream version as a .deb package:

1. Prepare the envorinment by creating a directory and setting the GOPATH and PATH variable:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.go/bin
   echo "GOPATH DEFAULT=\${HOME}/.go" >> ~/.pam_environment
   echo "PATH DEFAULT=\${PATH}:\$GOPATH/bin" >> ~/.pam_environment
   # Re-login your user so the variables are applied
   ```
2. Download, unpack and install the latest Go version with godeb:

   ```
   wget -O /tmp/godeb-amd64.tar.gz https://godeb.s3.amazonaws.com/godeb-amd64.tar.gz
   tar xfz /tmp/godeb-amd64.tar.gz -C ~/.go/bin
   godeb install
   ```

   Go is now ready to use. For more information, see `godeb --help`.

Comment: 2016 here. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, just discovered this myself as the correct answer. You can read a blog post about it here. http://blog.labix.org/2013/06/15/in-flight-deb-packages-of-go

Comment: On Ubuntu Xenial, the "prepare environment" instructions don't work for me. The .pam_environment is executed, but `${HOME}` apparently is empty, so GOPATH ends up as `/.go`, which is a no-go.

Comment: See [my answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130239/355438) for info on how to install go `v1.11` from the gophers archive PPA.

Answer (score 5):

I've not been able to find a PPA, but the `gccgo` developer has posted .deb packages on his [sourceforge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gccgo/files/).

Individuals have been working on packaging upstream Go in Debian, see the [WNPP bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=574371) for more info. You might be able to build a deb from the `hg` repo as folloows:

```
hg clone http://hg.debian.org/hg/collab-maint/golang/
cd golang
debuild -us -uc
```

I'm not terribly familiar with using `hg` to build debian packages, and keep in mind this is development packaging you're working with.

Comment: `abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

Answer (score 5):

I used this one `ppa:ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable` that has the near to latest version

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? They actually provide a package of golang with version 1.6 beta. It worked well for me!

Comment: Corresponding Launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/lxd-stable

Comment: This is what I have been using but they are currently lagging behind. Right now their version is 1.6.2, but 1.6.3 and 1.7 have been released.

Answer (score 0):

gccgo has official .deb packages in Debian experimental now.

This should be all you need to compile go code into an executable.

More info and links here:

- [Go (golang) intro incl. availability of packages in main distributions](http://gnubyexample.blogspot.com/2011/01/c-python-go-vala-mono-what-go-has-to.html)

As latest Ubuntu is usually a pull from experimental, then it should certainly be in 11.04 Natty Narwhal.

If you want roll you own .deb for a previous Ubuntu version, then comment from @lfaraone will get you access to debianized selection of google's own source.

If you want to pull the source direct from Google then there is a recent article by @mirwing telling you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go versions 1.4 through 1.11 for Ubuntu Trusty, Xenial, Bionic, Cosmic and Disco can be installed from here:
https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/ubuntu/archive

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gophers/go
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang-1.11-go
```

**Note:** After install, you will need to add `/usr/lib/go-1.X/bin` (or maybe `/usr/lib/go-tip/bin`) to your `$PATH`, or you can just invoke `/usr/lib/go-1.X/bin/go` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I got gpg failure gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name

Interestingly it on snap, so snap user can easily type
`sudo snap install go --classic` but remember if you already have go you should apt remove **go-lang** before install **go**

> in case someone faces 404