# What are PPAs and how do I use them?

Tags: ppa

I keep reading about [Personal Package Archives](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) ('PPAs') and people answer questions with a link to a PPA. What's the best way to use these?

---

There are multiple valid answers for this question spanning over several versions of Ubuntu. For your convenience, an index of each is below.

- [Ubuntu 11.04 and newer](https://askubuntu.com/a/40351)
- [Ubuntu 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/5102)
- [Ubuntu 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/5139)
- [Command Line](https://askubuntu.com/a/4987)

---

- [What is a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/a/4990)
- [Removing a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/91660)

Comment: Since none of the answers actually explain what a PPA is (focusing on how to add them), please think twice before closing "what is a PPA" type questions as duplicates and linking here.  Leaving one of them open might actually encourage someone to answer.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

## For Ubuntu 11.04 and newer

Before adding a PPA you should be aware of some of the risks involved:

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Always remember that PPAs are provided by the community, you should be aware of the possible risks before just adding a PPA.

- First open the dash by either clicking on the Home button (On the top-left Corner) or pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> Key .

  [image]
- Search for 'Software Center' and launch the Ubuntu software center.

  [image]
- Move the mouse to the top panel where the name of the application is written.
- Now Go to the *Edit* menu and select *Software Sources*.

  [image]

For newer versions,  right click and click **Software and Updates**
[image]

Then, click Other Software,
[image]

- Enter your password when prompted.

  [image]
- Switch to the 'Other Software' tab.

  [image]
- Now  click 'Add', a box will appear.

  [image]
- You have to enter the PPA in the box. It can be found in **BOLD** on the launchpad page.

  [image]

  [image]
- Now click 'Add source' and close the Software Sources. The cache will be refreshed

  [image]
- Now install the software from the software center.

  [image]

Comment: Wow, cool. Ubuntu has a nice, user-friendly interface for- "Enter the complete APT line of the repository you want to add as source." ...oh. Nevermind. ;-)

Comment: Nice up until the absence of the explanation on where to get the APT Line content for a PPA. :)

Comment: This answer is outdated. For an up-to-date guide see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-ppa.html).

Comment: How can I install software on PPA without adding it to the sources list? Can I even install it in a separate installation (Independent of the system)?

Comment: This doesn't even answer the OP's first question - what are PPAs.

Comment: +1  @antikbd  Outrageous that an avoidance of an answer is the top-rated answer.

Answer (score 186):

## What is PPA?

PPAs are for non standard software/updates. They are generally used by people who want the latest and greatest. If you are going extra lengths to get this kind of software, then you are expected to know what you are doing. The selection in the Software Centre is ample for most human beings.

## Command Line

On the command line you can add a PPA using `add-apt-repository`, e.g.:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa
```

To remove a PPA remove the corresponding files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d (this does not remove the packages you installed from the PPA). To see the packages available from a PPA or remove packages installed from a PPA press the "Origin" button on the lower left of the Synaptic window and choose the PPA from the list.

With can use the usual Software Sources dialog and add *ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa* where it asks for a *APT line* and enable or disable them just like other repositories.

As anybody can create a PPA there's no guarantee for quality or security of a PPA - just like with any other unofficial software source you have to decide yourself if a PPA it's trustworthy or not. And like any other unofficial software packages from a PPA can cause all sorts of difficulties especially when upgrading to a new release of Ubuntu.

---

If you get an error that the `add-apt-repository` command could not be found:

- On 12.04 and earlier, install the `python-software-properties` package:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
  ```
- On 14.04 and later:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
  ```

Comment: It bothers me that on the linux that claims to be for human beings adding a ppa requires either magic text on the command line or magic text added to a gui tool. It really isn't good enough.

Comment: PPAs are for non standard software/updates. They are generally used by people who want the latest and greatest. If you are going extra lengths to get this kind of software, then you are expected to know what you are doing. The selection in the Software Centre is ample for most human beings.

Comment: @trampster: These issues are going to be handled by the software center in the future: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter In the meantime PPAs is what we have.

Comment: I don't see what's difficult: You just go to a web page and copy a short line of text into a dialog window and then install your programs and automatically get updates for them. I've never seen anything comparable simple for Mac or Windows.

Comment: What I would prefer is download a file, double clicking on it, It asks for my password and then adds the ppa it's for. When asked for help by my none tech family, they switch off as soon as they realize they need to enter or even cut and paste random text to do the update. Even better would be to have the option in the software center as Jorge pointed out.

Comment: @trampster Does Windows/Mac keep on top of all its software, giving you updates to it all? PPAs are a security risk and there needs an element of design to stop users being idiots. More: http://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/

Comment: The recent high demand for PPAs seems to be a result of the dramatic changes in Ubuntu recently, making the stable versions woefully inadequate for a large number of people. This is the first release where I've needed to add more than 1 or 2 fairly unimportant PPAs - previously it has been only to test bug-fixes for me.

Comment: This command is not available in a vanilla install of 12.04 server and requires the python-software-properties package

Comment: @trampster You are being silly with your "single successful" comparison of Ubuntu with proprietary operating systems. If Ubuntu is more difficult than other Linux distributions, then you have a point.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `apt-add-repository` doesn't actually install anything from the PPA. One would need to issue `apt-get install` to "get" the software in the PPA and use it.

Comment: `What is PPA? PPAs are for non standard software/updates. ` That doesn't answer "what a PPA **is**?", it answers "what a PPA **is for**?"

Answer (score 97):

## For Ubuntu 10.10

While many find it easier to add PPAs using command line tools, this can be done through **Ubuntu Software Center** for those who prefer graphical interfaces. For this demo, we will be adding the [PPA for the Banshee Team](https://edge.launchpad.net/%7Ebanshee-team/+archive/ppa) in order to get the latest stable release of Banshee.

We'll begin by opening the Ubuntu Software Center which can be found in the Applications menu.

```
Applications > Ubuntu Software Center
```

[image: manu]

Now in Software Center, go to `Edit > Software Sources`

[image: menu2]

You will be asked to enter your administrative password.

[image: gksu]

Now in Software Sources open the `Other Software` tab and press `Add`.

[image: add]

In this dialog, we will enter the PPA's information.

[image: software-properties-gtk]

This information is found on the PPA's website in bold under the heading **Adding this PPA to your system**. For the [Banshee PPA](https://edge.launchpad.net/%7Ebanshee-team/+archive/ppa), it looks like this:

[image: ppa]

Now we can close Software Sources and Software Center will automatically update so that you can access the new packages from the PPA.

[image: update]

The packages available from the PPA can be seen by expanding the Get Software menu in Software Center's left column.

[image: new]

Comment: It's a "community wiki" so feel free to expand on it.

Comment: Is that the default Iconset for 10.10?

Comment: No, I forgot I wasn't using the default icons when I took those. That is the `faenza-icon-theme`. It is available in this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox

Answer (score 50):

## For Ubuntu 10.04

To add a PPA in Ubuntu 10.04:

- Run System->Administration->Software Sources:

[image: menu]

- You will be prompted for your password. Note that you can only add a PPA if you are an administrator user due to the security risks and system wide consequences of adding a PPA. Enter your password into the dialog to continue:

[image: gksu]

- In the Software Sources window, click on the 'Other Software' tab and click the 'Add...' button. This will bring up a prompt asking for the 'APT line':

[image: apt line]

- The text to paste into this box is found on the launchpad page in the 'Adding This PPA to your System' in bold letter.

[image]

- Paste the line you copied into the text box in Software Sources (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>):

[image]

- Close the Software Sources window; you will be asked to reload your package information. Do this by clicking the 'Reload' button:

[image: reload sources]

- You can now find software packages from this PPA in Ubuntu Software Centre:

[image: software centre]

Answer (score 45):

### What is a PPA?

It's all very simple once you get the hang of it.  I have run into problems here and there, but generally speaking, PPA's are the only way to get your software updated in Ubuntu between distro releases (don't get me into a rant about that).  It's too much to explain here, so I will point you to some worthwhile documentation.  But first, a few simple rules:

Know what you're installing.  Most likely you'll use Launchpad for the majority of your PPA needs, but even so it can be dangerous to your computer.  Usually the worry for me is not malicious intent, but conflicting packages.  If package A requires a modified version of ffmpeg, and package B in a different repository requires a modified version of ffmpeg too, well, now there's a good chance you might not be able to watch videos, for example, with package A or B or at all.

Keep in mind that anyone can create a PPA, even you.  Just because a person signs the Code of Conduct doesn't mean they know what they're doing.  On Launchpad there is not only updates to stable releases, but also beta and alpha software, and even stuff that doesn't quite work at all yet.  There are many useful repositories, such as to get the latest Nvidia drivers or the current stable release of Pidgin.  Then again, there's stuff that some guy made in his basement for himself and a couple of friends.

That said, the Ubuntu documentation web pages should have everything you need to know in a pretty understandable format.

Repositories in Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Software management: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement

Repositories and the command line: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

A quick note: I assume you're using Ubuntu 10.04.  If you're using 10.10 there is no more "Software Sources" in your menu, even though it is referred to in some of the documentation.  To access it simply open the Synaptic Package Manager then select Settings -> Repositories from the menu.

Good Luck and I hope this was helpful.

Edit: Please know that installing software through the Ubuntu Software Center can be troublesome.  This is because it does not tell you what dependencies a particular app you want to install requires.  That is, you could install the entire KDE desktop, hundreds of MB's worth of stuff, just to get a screen ruler or firewall configurator.  I learned this the hard way...  For example, type "kruler" in the search box and you will see the final install size as almost 100 MB.  At least pay close attention to the final install size if you insist on using the USC.  Most new users are unfamiliar with the concepts of window managers and desktop environments having only known Windows, so be careful about simply relying on USC and not learning all about PPAs, which is what I recommend.  It's a little more work and this is just my opinion, but you'll probably be happy you did! :)

Answer (score 40):

One thing to keep in mind about using PPAs is that when you add a PPA to your Software Sources, you're giving Administrative access (root) to everyone that can upload to that PPA. Packages in PPAs have access to your entire system as they get installed (just like a regular package from the main Ubuntu Archive), so always decide if you trust a PPA before you add it to your system.

Comment: Very important comment this one. It's really important advertise for potential damage to the system by using ppa's without knowledge. THNX

Answer (score 26):

### Removing a PPA with [ppa-purge](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ppa-purge) [image: Install ppa-purge]

It may not be safe to just disable any PPA added to our sources by removing it from `sources.list` or by unticking the PPA in our *Software Sources* settings. It would then be a much better idea to also remove all packages that were installed from this PPA and replace them with Ubuntu default packages.

To do so we have the script [ppa-purge](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ppa-purge) [image: Install ppa-purge] that will not only remove the unwanted PPA but also will replace packages that were installed from this PPA by the default Ubuntu versions. After installation simply run

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:<lp-name>/<ppa-name>
```

where `<lp-name>/<ppa-name>` is the same name we entered to our sources when adding this PPA. The PPA will then be removed. Packages installed from this PPA will be replaced by default Ubuntu packages (installed packages that are not in the default repositories will not be deleted).

Comment: As an answer with a comment pointing to ppa-purge was removed, I felt we may still need a reference for this in our list of answers on how to use a PPA.

Comment: What does `lp` stand for? For example in `precise-partner.list` what is the `lp`?

Comment: @isomorphismes: Ubuntu PPA are hosted on launchpad (lp) with their specifc name and sub-name, e.g. `ppa:takkat-nebuk/takkat`. In this example `takkat-nebuk` is my lp-name and `takkat` is the name of the ppa to add to your sources.

Answer (score 21):

If you are having a hard time figuring out the correct `add-apt-repository` command to run, someone has created a script called `ppasearch` to make this task easier. To install ppasearch, you will need to run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wrinkliez/ppasearch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppasearch
```

If you are on maverick, you can manually [download](https://edge.launchpad.net/~wrinkliez/+archive/ppasearch/+files/ppasearch_0.7.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb) and install the lucid deb. It should work fine.

This will add the ppasearch PPA (and its key) and install the package. You can run the script by typing the following command in a terminal:

`ppasearch PPANAME`

So to find the Cardapio team PPA, you might run:

`ppasearch cardapio`

As you can see from the screenshot below, you are then presented with a list of matching PPAs. Once you select the PPA you want, it will get added by the script by using `add-apt-repository`. ppasearch will even run `sudo apt-get update` for you if you wish to update your sources.

[image: ppasearch screenshot]

There is also a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyA9QGgALPQ) of the script in action, but it is slightly out-of-date.

This script should make it easy for you to add PPAs and their keys without having to search around Launchpad.

Comment: Tried this PPA in 2014 and couldn't find http://ppa.launchpad.net/wrinkliez/ppasearch/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages. `404`

Comment: Appears to be abondonware

Answer (score 5):

http://www.winehq.org/site/download-deb  is my attempt at doing this for the Wine PPA.

I'll note that Maverick changed and now I have to edit the instructions again (there is no more administration->software sources but instead you have to go there from Software Center).

Launchpad's built in instructions are a bit better than they were a year or so ago, but still pretty bad.

Answer (score 5):

For Information on PPA (**Personal Package Archive**) Visit Ubuntu help on [PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA).

---

There is [Y PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager) available for Ubuntu. It is a GUI tool to manage PPAs in the best possible way.

To install `y-ppa-manager` run following command in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

For more information and key-features, visit https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager.

---

**How to find PPA?** (Solution when `apt` unable to locate package)

You can find PPA from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) page as suggested in following image:

---

[image: adding ppa to your system]

---

You can find PPA from [Ubuntuupdates](http://ubuntuupdates.org) -Package Search as shown in the following picture:

---

[image: adding third party repository]

---

Then Add repository from terminal as following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<someppa/ppa>
sudo apt-get update
```